# Which programming forum is best for Opinion based questions?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I want to learn one functional programming language. I would like to know pros/cons of various  candidates based on some assumptions (to be specified in question).

Now as it is Opinion based, [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) is definitely not a place.  [Progammers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)  could be one place, but [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) suggest other wise.

Is there any suitable SE forum where opinion based questions are allowed?

Comment: There is no such SE site

Comment: To be clear: there is a strong difference between _opinion_-based and _subjective_ questions. Questions can be subjective, as long as their answers can be substantiated by hard evidence. Questions whose answers depend solely on opinion, however, do not fit.

Answer (score 5):

## No.

The SE system of voting on answers just doesn't work well for opinion based questions. Programmers actually started out as an 'opinion-based' site, but it wasn't really working - so its scope was overhauled.

No SE sites accept opinion based questions.

Comment: so, to summarise, the answer is no? ...;)

Comment: It is flawed with the reputation system. It might work if answers could be upvoted or downvoted without change of reputation like happens on meta sites which are opinion based.

Comment: how wasn't it working?